# Solve $(x-5)/(x+1)= (x-5)/(x+3)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Someone is asked to solve the following equation: $(x-5)/(x+1)= (x-5)/(x+3)$. This person respond "There is no solution. Cross multiply to get $(x-5)(x+3)=(x-5)(x+1)$. Divide both sides by $x-5$ and I get $x+3=x+1$. Subtracting $x$ from both sides, I get $1=3$ which is impossible. So there is no solution." Is this person right?

I mean the person is right but instead of subtracting $x$, wouldn't you subtract the constants. So I would subtract 1 on both sides and get $x+2=x$ and subtract $x$ and you get $0=2$ which is not true.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint:  you may not be able to divide by $(x-5)$.

Comment: Notice that $x=5$ is a solution, so there's something wrong with your argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all $x$ must be different from $-1$ and $-3$.

Then, $x=5$ is obviously a solution, since $0=0$.

Supposing moreover $x\neq5$, we can divide both sides by $(x-5)$ and get
$$
\frac1{x+1}=\frac1{x+3}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
x+1=x+3
$$
but this last one is clearly always false.

Thus the only solution of your initial equation is $x=5$.

Answer (score 3):

Cross multiplying is ok, but first you must specify that $x \neq -1,-3$, or the values for which the denominators are null, and you cannot divide by $(x-5)$ without first stating $x \neq 5$ (infact one/the only solution is $x = 5$)

Rather, multiply out to get a polynomial, like the following (after setting $x \neq -1,-3$):
$$
(x-5)(x+3)=(x-5)(x+1)
$$
Then:
$$
x^2-2x-15 = x^2-4x-5
$$
Finally $2x=10$, so $x=5$

Answer (score 2):

By the same logic of that person, the identity
$$
\frac{0}{1}=\frac{0}{2}
$$
is false because you can factor out $0$ and get the false identity
$$
\frac{1}{1}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

Or you can deduce the well known fact that $2=1$: set $x=y=1$; then $x^2-y^2=x^2-xy$ and you can factor out $x-y$ from both sides, getting
$$
x+y=x
$$
that is, $2=1$.

---

***If*** $x\ne 5$, you can factor out $x-5$ from both sides, getting
$$
\frac{1}{x+3}=\frac{1}{x+1}
$$
that's clearly false for every $x$ (of course we cannot consider $-3$ or $-1$ to begin with).

However, for $x=5$, the left-hand side is equal to the right-hand side. So $5$ is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot divide by $(x-5)$ when $x=5$. So, $x=5$ is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you cross multiply and simplify $ (x-5)= 0, x = 5 $. Do not divide by a zero on either side of equation.

Answer (score 0):

After cross multiplying, expand each side of the equation $ (x-5)(x+3) = (x-5)(x+1) $ as a quadratic expression.

On the left side: $ (x-5)(x+3) = x^{2}+3x-5x-15 $ $$= x^{2}-2x-15 $$

On the right side: $(x-5)(x+1) = x^{2}+x-5x-5 $ $$= x^{2}-4x-5$$

Thus, $$ (x-5)(x+3) = (x-5)(x+1) $$
$$<=> x^{2}-2x-15 = x^{2}-4x-5 $$

The $ x^{2}$ terms on each side cancel each other out, so we are left with
$$ -2x - 15 = -4x - 5 $$

Add $ 2x $ to each side:

$$ -2x - 15 +2x = -4x - 5 +2x $$
$$<=> -15 = -2x-5$$

Add $ 5 $ to each side:
$$ -15 + 5 = -2x-5 + 5$$
$$<=> -10 = -2x $$

Finally divide a $-2$ to each side:
$$ \frac{-10}{-2} = \frac{-2x}{-2} $$
$$<=> 5 = x $$

Thus $ x = 5 $ is a solution that is not extraneous.